# set up a cron job with PHP in Google App Engine

Tags: php, cron, google-cloud-platform

cron.yaml

[image: cron.yaml]

app.yaml

[app.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3nYU.jpg)

However, There are no cron jobs listed on the console. Whats wrong?

Comment: Where are you looking in the console? Are you looking under *App Engine* > *Task Queues* > *Cron Jobs*?

Comment: Also have you deployed your `cron.yaml` via the gcloud command?

`gcloud preview app deploy cron.yaml`